# Telnet client for Android

Tags: android, command-line, network-monitor, communication, telnet

I looked on the Play store for Telnet Client and saw [one by ClockworkMod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=koushikdutta.telnet) and thought "Oooo, a reputable client!" but the permissions scared me off.  There was another that required GPS location.

What is a good (i.e. functioning) telnet client for Android?

Features I am looking for:

1. Reputable software
2. No ads
3. No root requirements, but maybe more features if the phone is rooted.
4. Support the telnet protocol
5. Landscape mode support

Nice to haves:

1. Free app
2. SSH
3. Support additional protocols

The telnet client can be a part of a suite or it can be stand alone.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Irssi ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.woltage.irssiconnectbot):

- Free, open-source software
- Supports Telnet, SSH, and [MOSH](https://mosh.mit.edu/) if you [download the version that has the mosh patches](http://dan.drown.org/android/mosh/)
- Reputable, with over 1700 reviews on Google Play
- No ads
- No root required
- Supports landscape mode (try the **Force Landscape** option under the Terminal Emulation options)

Comment: Needs access to photo & media files??!!  Nevertheless, I tried it and like it, so plus one.

Comment: Yeah, not sure what that is about. Might be worth popping into IRCnet on the channel #irssiconnectbot to ask the developers :-)

Comment: Probably it's to look for the private keys for SSH connection. ConnectBot is great, with mosh it would be perfect! I didn't know about the mosh fork.

Comment: @Nemo -- /me slaps head. Yes, of course. It is for private keys.

Comment: Does it support port forwarding though SSH?

Comment: @Alejandro Yep!

Comment: About (Irssi) Connectbot: NO echo in telnet mode ! ):

Answer (score 1):

I have been used many of them but found this one is the best for me.
It's simply, compact and direct to your job.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb1sIatpUl0&feature=youtu.be

the App download link is here.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nristek.apps.netztools

Comment: What is your recommendation? Can you list the main features of it and how it complies wih the question? A lone link may be a good supplement to your answer, but cannot be the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend GSW ConnectBot from Georgia SoftWorks if you need a commercial grade client. Excellent client with very strong encryption using SSH.

https://www.georgiasoftworks.com/connectbot-client-android.

Comment: Thanks Sam, and welcome.  Does your recommendation meet all of the requirements?

Comment: I believe it does with the exception of "free", otherwise, it has all the features YARU was looking for.